# Chrome makes way too many requests (~22000) while downloading MP4 video (~34MB)

Tags: nginx, http, google-chrome

We host some video files (mp4) on our site.

All the files are loaded way too slow in Google Chrome, in FF everything is OK.
I tested downloading of a file with size of 34MB (I opened the file by a direct link). The results are:

- *Chrome* made **~22000(!)** requests, **982MB** transferred.
- *Firefox* made only 5 requests.

As a server we use *nginx* with default (related to video files serving) settings.

Here the interaction (the first five requests) beetwen Chrome and the server. Only `Range`, `Content-Length`, `Content-Range` headers included.
(< - header sent by Chrome, < - one sent by the server):

```
> Initial request for file, usual GET  
< Content-Length:35690389  
< Content-Type:video/mp4  

Then a bunch of similar requests, on which the server responded with 206 status code:  
---  
> Range:bytes=0-  
< Content-Length:35690389  
< Content-Range:bytes 0-35690388/35690389  
---   
> Range:bytes=29100305-  
< Content-Length:6590084  
< Content-Range:bytes 29100305-35690388/35690389  
---  
> Range:bytes=35566374-   
< Content-Length:124015  
< Content-Range:bytes 35566374-35690388/35690389  
---  
> Range:bytes=32-  
< Content-Length:35690357  
< Content-Range:bytes 32-35690388/35690389
```

Looks like Chrome misunderstand some headers which are sent from the server (e.g. Range) and downloads the same pieces of file many times.

What might cause the problem? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was caused by video files (namely by the converter that was used).
The files which caused the problem were converted with *Format Factory v2.6*.
After upgrade to *v3.7* and reconverting the problem disappeared.

What makes Chrome make so many requests during playing such videos still unknown ...

Comment: Have you asked the converter's author about the cause?

Comment: @VladislavRastrusny No I haven't . The version that caused the problem is very outdated, if I got it right it even from 2010.

Comment: I see. Well, I guess they would like to hear about the problem. At least if it is not yet in their changelog.

Comment: We have similar probles with our mp4 files longer then 1 hour or bigger than 700 Mb. We render it with Adobe Premiere. I found that rerender it with ffmpeg helps: ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy out.mp4 -movflags +faststart